# how to close dropdown on click in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

i have a website where there is a dropdown like below:

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="shop_submenu" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Rent
                      </a>
  <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="shop_submenu">


    <li><a href="">Short Gowns</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Couple Combo Sherwani</a></li>

  </ul>
</li>
```

the javascript code is like below:

```js
(function($bs) {
  const CLASS_NAME = 'has-child-dropdown-show';
  $bs.Dropdown.prototype.toggle = function(_orginal) {
    return function() {
      document.querySelectorAll('.' + CLASS_NAME).forEach(function(e) {
        e.classList.remove(CLASS_NAME);
      });
      let dd = this._element.closest('.dropdown').parentNode.closest('.dropdown');
      for (; dd && dd !== document; dd = dd.parentNode.closest('.dropdown')) {
        dd.classList.add(CLASS_NAME);
      }
      return _orginal.call(this);
    }
  }($bs.Dropdown.prototype.toggle);

  document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown').forEach(function(dd) {
    dd.addEventListener('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
      if (this.classList.contains(CLASS_NAME)) {
        this.classList.remove(CLASS_NAME);
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      e.stopPropagation(); // do not need pop in multi level mode
    });
  });

  // for hover
  document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-hover, .dropdown-hover-all .dropdown').forEach(function(dd) {
    dd.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
      let toggle = e.target.querySelector(':scope>[data-bs-toggle="dropdown"]');
      if (!toggle.classList.contains('show')) {
        $bs.Dropdown.getOrCreateInstance(toggle).toggle();
        dd.classList.add(CLASS_NAME);
        $bs.Dropdown.clearMenus();
      }
    });
    dd.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
      let toggle = e.target.querySelector(':scope>[data-bs-toggle="dropdown"]');
      if (toggle.classList.contains('show')) {
        $bs.Dropdown.getOrCreateInstance(toggle).toggle();
      }
    });
  });
})(bootstrap);
```

this is working fine fore opening, now i want to close it when the user clicks on it again, can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? `dd.classList.remove(CLASS_NAME);` Like this:

```
    dd.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (e) {
      let toggle = e.target.querySelector(':scope>[data-bs-toggle="dropdown"]');
      if (toggle.classList.contains("show")) {
        $bs.Dropdown.getOrCreateInstance(toggle).toggle();
        dd.classList.remove(CLASS_NAME);
      }
    });
  });
})(bootstrap);
```

Doesn't look like you're removing the class name on mouseleave? If you don't remove it it will still be shown. Also, I'm not sure what kind of event this is `dd.addEventListener("hide.bs.dropdown" . . .` but evidently you have some custom event called "hide.bs.dropdown" that fires from somewhere else.

Comment: i tried this, but it doesnt work